# React component not animated with linaria

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have component whose width must change in depends of props.

My style for component:

```
  const SidebarContainer = styled.div`
    width: ${props.isOpen ? 340 : 73}px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: ${colors.white100};
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
`
```

Styles changing, but without transition. I tried to use data [attributes](https://github.com/callstack/linaria/blob/master/docs/DYNAMIC_STYLES.md) but it not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try width: ${({ isOpen }) => (isOpen ? '340' : '73')}px

Comment: Try ${({props. isOpen }) => (props.isOpen ? '340' : '73')}px, but nothing

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by `styled-tools` and `ifProp`

```
import { ifProp } from 'styled-tools';

const SidebarContainer = styled.div<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
  width: ${ifProp('isOpen', 34, 7.5)}rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: ${colors.white100};
  padding-top: 1.7rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-box: box-sizing;
`;
```